# Idiomatic way to join on "secondary" keys

Tags: apache-beam

If we have a stream that looks like this

```
Person {
     …
     OrganizationID
}
```

that we want to join with another stream

```
Organization {
     ID
     …
}
```

to create a composite record like so:

```
Person {
     …
     Organization {
           ID
           …
     }
}
```

What is the most **idiomatic** and **efficient** way to do so in the **Apache Beam programming model**?

NB: have seen `side input`s recommended as a solution to similar problems like this, but it is not applicable here since the effect we are after is that *every change* to either `Person` **or** `Organization` should yield a new augmented `Person`-record.

Comment: This question would be more answerable if you could specify the desired balance of latency versus cost.

Comment: @KennKnowles — latency is not so important, so long as a new Persons are always emitted for each change in Organization.

Comment: How about the cost? Conceptually if you do not specify cost limitation, all elements will be buffered from both stream. Say if there is a new org id appear on org stream, all person with the same org id is supposed to be buffered at that moment and then emits all new joined elements (of course some optimization can be done. e.g drop person events that has been joined)

Comment: Yes, I understand that that would have to be the case. But lets assume Person and Organization are ”fairly small” (N ~1-100M records). Anyway would be interesting to hear the different options based on different answers to the cost question.

Comment: Given unlimited storage, my answer will apply then.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

The answer is, your example is not supported by Apache Beam due to missing retraction in Apache Beam implementation.

===================================================

Original answer:

You might want to check Join library[1] in Apache Beam.

Join in Beam model needs extra thinking on windowing strategies on your streams. Sounds like your streams does not require windowing, so say your streams are both in global window. But if you set global window on both of your streams, use default trigger and do Join like Beam's Join library, due to watermark never passes endless window, your Join will not emit any result. If you set repeatly data driven trigger (fire once seen enough elements), however, due to missing supporting for retraction in Beam, it's not clear how pre-emited result is refined for Join.

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/join-library/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.java#L49

Comment: The join lib assumes that the keys are equal — they are not in my example.

Comment: @salient Do you join Person.OrganizationID on Organization.ID?

Comment: Then you can have  PCollections of KV<OrganizationID, Person> and KV<ID, Organization> and then join them together. The Key in Join library is a type, as long as your ID in Person and Org are same type, they can be joined: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/join-library/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.java#L43